# Hermitian connection on a complex vector bundle

Tags: complex-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

Let
$$\pi:E\longrightarrow M$$
be a complex vector bundle with an hermitian metric $h$. I am using Griffiths and Harris' *Principles of Algebraic Geometry*, where it defines a connection on $E$ as a map
$$D:A^0(E)\longrightarrow A^1(E)$$
such that
$$D(f\sigma+\tau)=df\otimes\sigma+fD\sigma+D\tau$$
and it says that the connection is compatible with the metric if
$$dh(\sigma,\tau)=h(D\sigma,\tau)+h(\sigma,D\tau)$$

I don't understand what the rhs means, since
$$\tau\in A^0(E),\quad D\sigma\in A^1(E)\Rightarrow \tau(x)\in E_x$$
but
$$(D\sigma)(x):T_xM\longrightarrow E_x$$
so how do apply $h$ to that pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well $dh(\sigma,\tau)$ is a one-form that eats tangent vectors. So is the right-hand side. So it means

$$dh(\sigma,\tau)(v)=h(D_v\sigma,\tau)+h(\sigma,D_v\tau).$$

Now the arguments of the metric on the right-hand side are sections of $E$, and everything makes sense.

Comment: The moment I can't see this by myself is the moment to take a break..